# Error when calling C++ function from R and integrate it

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, integrate

I want to numerically integrate a 1-dimensional function (that was written in C++) with the R function `integrate`. As a short example, I coded the function `myfunc` in C++.

```
    #include <cmath>
    #include <Rcpp.h>

    using namespace std;

    // [[Rcpp::export]]

    double myfunc (double x){
        double result;
        result = exp( -0.5*pow(x,2) + 2*x );
        return result;
    }
```

After loading `myfunc` in R and integrating it, I obtain the following error:

```
    library(Rcpp)
    sourceCpp("myfunc.cpp")
    integrate(myfunc,lower=0,upper=10)
```

*Error in f(x, ...) : Expecting a single value: [extent=21].*

Can anyone explain what this error means and how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

From `help("integrate")`:

> f must accept a vector of inputs and produce a vector of function evaluations at those points. The Vectorize function may be helpful to convert f to this form.

You have created your function to accept a single value, a `double`, so when `integrate()` tries to pass it a vector, it rightfully complains. So, try

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector myfunc(Rcpp::NumericVector x){
    return exp(-0.5 * pow(x, 2) + 2 * x);
}

/*** R
integrate(myfunc, lower = 0, upper = 10)
*/
```

Resulting in

```
integrate(myfunc, lower = 0, upper = 10)
# 18.10025 with absolute error < 5.1e-08
```

Or, using `myfunc()` compiled from your C++ code from above,

```
f <- Vectorize(myfunc)
integrate(f, lower = 0, upper = 10)
# 18.10025 with absolute error < 5.1e-08
```

Comment: Amazing what reading the manual can accomplish :)  Congrats also on getting `RcppDist` onto CRAN!

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel ! Expect a pull request for an Rcpp Gallery post on `RcppDist` in a day or two.